# How to limit the number of posts in the wordpress loop in conjunction with the "download more" button?

Tags: php, functions

Sorry for my bad english. In the template of the main page, posts are displayed, for some reason 14 items on the blog page, as well as the same posts, it is necessary that the main loaded 6 and loaded with a button as 6 posts, and on the blog page all the same, only 9 I tried different methods, but I did not find a single solution, either I work on 6 posts, but
the "load more" button does not work, or the button loads 6, but it is displayed on the page initially. I will attach the code below.

index.php

```
<div class="projects">
        <?php
                    query_posts( array(
                            'post_type' => 'post'
                    ) );
                    if( have_posts() ){
                        while( have_posts() ){
                            the_post();
                            $i = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
                            ?>
                            <div class="project">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><div class="project-img" style="background: url('<?php echo $i;?>')"></div></a>
                                <p class="may-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                <p class="may-annotice"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <p class="post-date"><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    } else {                 
                    }
                    ?>
        </div>

        <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
          <script>
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
            var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
            var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
            var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
          </script>
          <div id="true_loadmore" class="watch hover-blue">Загрузить ещё</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- button for load more posts  -->            
      </div>
```

functions.php

```
    /* new ajax load more */
    function true_loadmore_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'true_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/loadmore.js', array('jquery') );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'true_loadmore_scripts' );


    function true_load_posts(){
        $args = unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['query']));
        $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // следующая страница
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $q = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $q->have_posts() ):
            while($q->have_posts()): $q->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="project">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><div class="project-img" style="background: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>')"></div></a>
                    <p class="may-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                    <p class="may-annotice"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <p class="post-date"><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
/* new ajax load more */

/* number of posts in page */
function custom_posts_per_page($query){
    if(is_home()){ $query->set('posts_per_page',6); }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_posts_per_page');
/* number of posts in page */
```

loadmore.js

```
   jQuery(function($){
  $('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
    $(this).text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки, вы также можете добавить прелоадер
    var data = {
      'action': 'loadmore',
      'query': true_posts,
      'page' : current_page
    };
    $.ajax({
      url:ajaxurl, // обработчик
      data:data, // данные
      type:'POST', // тип запроса
      success:function(data){
        if( data ) { 
          $('#true_loadmore').text('Загрузить ещё').before(data); // вставляем новые посты
          current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
          if (current_page == max_pages) $("#true_loadmore").remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
        } else {
          $('#true_loadmore').remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This way, 14 records are output and there is a button for Ajax loading posts for 6 pieces, but if I replace the loop with this one, then the button disappears, but it shows up how I need 6 posts.

```
<div class="projects">
    <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 6);
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post);?>
        <div class="project">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><div class="project-img" style="background: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>')"></div></a>
          <p class="may-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
          <p class="may-annotice"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
          <p class="post-date"><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- button for load more posts  -->
    <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
      <script>
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
        var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
        var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
      </script>
      <div id="true_loadmore" class="watch hover-blue">Загрузить ещё</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- button for load more posts  -->                
  </div>
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `query_posts` use `WP_query` and use `post_per_page` argument to limit number of posts returned

Comment: Yes, if i use get_posts in last code here button disapear.